# How to configure my 2 router to make them as access points

Tags: ip, router, dhcp, wireless-networking, wireless-access-point

I have this broadband and the main wireless router: [Main Router](http://help.virginmedia.com/system/selfservice.controller?CMD=VIEW_ARTICLE&ARTICLE_ID=3859&CURRENT_CMD=SEARCH&CONFIGURATION=1001&PARTITION_ID=1&USERTYPE=1&LANGUAGE=en&COUNTY=us&VM_CUSTOMER_TYPE=Cable)

Also I have two other routers and would like to make them as access points. So All with the same SSID, then the device can choose the nearest router.

Here are my routers.

1. Netgear G Router WGR614
2. [D-Link Dir 619](http://www.dlink.com/us/en/home-solutions/connect/routers/dir-615-wireless-n-300-router)

Both of these are connected by cable, to the main router but I used powerline adapters for the second router as it is far from the main one.

Main router is on DHCP, 192.168.0.1.  The second router (D-link) has a an access point option and I tried it but it disconnects every hour for couple of minutes and reconnect again. Do not know the reason.

Anyway, what configuration should I do on each of the routers to make them as described ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There are a few potential issues that should be addressed before setting up these devices.

- How big is the location where you will be installing these AP's ? You will actually get worse performance if you put all 3 of these in a 2000 sqft house. Use only what you need, or turn *down* the power on the Access Point if possible.
- Are you planning on doing encryption? If so, you will need to use WPA, because the Netgear doesn't list WPA2 as one of the available encryption schemes.
- I would advise that you change your dhcp server to give out addresses in the 192.168.1.x subnet instead of the 192.168.0.x subnet. Theoretically all modern devices should be compatible with classless ip's, but I have seen issues with SOHO devices on this subnet.

---

**Configuration**

On the routers you wish to use as access points, you will need to perform the following actions:

- Turn off dhcp leasing
- Set a static IP that is within the subnet of the Virgin Mobile router

Once you have done that, plug the AP's into the network, *Making sure to plug into the LAN port, not the WAN port*

**Example**

Here is an example from my wireless router. It is running dd-wrt so the menu's will look different, but it is the same idea. 
My dhcp server is 10.90.4.1, so I configured my AP to a static address in the same subnet.

[image]

**Shared SSID**

In order to roam between wireless access points, you will need to verify the following:

- All AP's must have the same SSID
- All AP's must have the same encryption & password/key

Note that roaming works well and will have minor interruptions for basic internet tasks.
Roaming will not work well for streaming (Skype, Voip calls ect..).

Note that the IEEE is working on improving [Fast Secure Roaming](http://www.cwnp.com/cwnp_wifi_blog/wlan-controllers-and-fast-secure-roaming/) with the following standards:  [802.11k](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_802.11k-2008) and [802.11r](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_802.11r-2008)

**Wireless Channel Selection**

The channels that you choose to use are important. Download a wireless survey tool such as [Inssider](http://www.metageek.net/products/inssider/) (Windows) or [WiFi Explorer](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/wifi-explorer/id494803304?mt=12) (Mac). Walk around the location and take note of which channels are the least 'noisy'. Configure your AP to have the least amount of overlap with neighboring wireless networks.

Because you are on the 2.4GHZ [ISM band](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISM_band), there are 3 channels that have no [sideband](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sideband) interference. 1, 6, and 11.  You will want to put each AP on a different channel to avoid [co-channel interference.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Co-channel_interference) and [adjacent cell interference](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~luluo/Courses/15744writeup.pdf)

---

**Additional Information**

You may notice a channel 12, 13 and 14. Those my be used under special considerations.

Channel 12 & 13

- May be used for indoor only transmissions.
- May be used if the power does not exceed 1 Watt at the intentional radiator

Channel 14

- May not be used in the United States
- May be used in Japan
- May only be used for 802.11b transmissions.

Comment: Thank you for your post. I tried to follow your instruction, but there is a problem. To set the ip address of the AP, it only accept an IP in DHCP range and not somethng different.  For example I made my DHCP 192.168.0.4. So 0.1 is main router, 0.2 AP1 and 0.3 AP2 but in configuring each one of the APs it does not accept it.  In your case is 10.90.4.90 inside your DHCP range?

Comment: @KamranJafari Some devices do not support classless routing (192.168.0.x). Try moving everything to the 192.168.1.x subnet.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks @spuder for his help. His solution is correct and working. I would just add some more points.
First of as I wanted to add two Access Points, I changed the DHCP IP range. It's as below:

- Main Router - 192.168.0.1
- Access Point 1 - 192.168.0.2
- Access Point 2 - 192.168.0.3
- DHCP 192.168.0.4 to 192.168.0.X
  So in this way my access points' IP addresses will not be renewed every time. (As DHCP renew IP addresses time by time).

To make the router to AP you only need to open the LAN settings of the AP, change IP address, default getaway and subnet mask and then in wireless settings change the SSID and password the same as the main router.  Also chose a different channel as the other routers and APs.

Another thing which is really important is that, in connecting the cable from main router to AP, I used to connect it to the WAN port (the one with a different colour). In the correct setup you need to connect it to the an Ethernet port (numbered by 1, 2, 3, 4).

It's how my network works. @Spuder, thanks again for your help.

http://kb.netgear.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/19852/~/set-up-a-wireless-router-as-an-access-point-on-a-network